# rero-length ms_printf format string

Tags: c

Someone can expalain me why my code don't work?

```
 printf("Please enter a number for 7 boom game\n");
   scanf("%d",&n1);
   printf("[")     
   if(n1<7)
   printf("");
   else if (n1 >=7)
   printf("7")

   for (i=1;i<=n1;i++)
   {

    while((i!=0)&&(n1>=i)&&(i!=7))
    {
    if(i%10==7)
    printf(",%d",i);
    else if(i%7==0)
    printf(",%d",i);
    else
    {
    y1=i;
    while(y1!=0)
    {
    y1=y1/10;
    k++;

    }
    for(j=0;j<=k;j++)
    {
    div=div*10;

    }

    if((y1)%div==7)
    printf(",%d",i);

    }

    i++;

    }
    }
```

My output has to be: all the number that contain 7 like for 20 output is [7,14,17] and the number has to be in order?

Comment: Absense of function definition and definition of variables?

Comment: And absense of semicolon after `printf("[")` and `printf("7")`.

Comment: and also a zero length `printf("")` function

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: This code won't even compile.

Answer (score 0):

The code to find embedded `7`s is wrong. For example, when you get to this `if`, `y1` will always be `0`:

```
if((y1)%div==7)
    printf(",%d",i);
}
```

To find embedded `7`s you could do like this instead:

```
y1 = i;
do {
    if (y1%10 == 7) {
        // Last digit in y1 is 7
        printf(",%d",i);
        break;
    }
    y1 = y1 / 10;  // Remove last digit in y1
} while (y1 > 0)
```

Comment: Thanks you very much klas lindbäck